# How to JSONify a javascript object's properties

Tags: javascript, json

I'm doing a 'manual' run through my javascript class' properties in order to form JSON, as seen below. It feels clumsy and I would to learn how to do this automatically, so I wouldn't have to mess with the 'toJson' function if I add or remove any properties, for example.

Can a helpful mind point me in the right direction on how to adapt the below 'toJson' function towards this purpose?

Many thanks in advance.

```
/* Using Simple JavaScript Inheritance
* By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
* MIT Licensed.*/
var LogEntry = Class.extend({
    init: function (_conferenceId, _tokenId, _logType, _logValue) {
        this.dato = new Date();
        this.logValue = _logValue;
        this.logType = _logType;
        this.conferenceId = _conferenceId;
        this.tokenId = _tokenId;
    },
    toJson: function () {
        // ?
        var jsonStringBuilder = '{ ';
        jsonStringBuilder += '"dato": ' + this.dato.toString() + ',';
        jsonStringBuilder += '"conferenceId": ' + this.conferenceId + ',';
        if (this.tokenId== null) {
            jsonStringBuilder += '"tokenId":null,';
        }
        else {
            jsonStringBuilder += '"tokenId": ' + _tokenId + ',';
        }
        jsonStringBuilder += '"logValue": ' + this.logValue + ',';
        jsonStringBuilder += '"logType": ' + this.logType;
        jsonStringBuilder += '}';

        return jsonStringBuilder;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is the function you're looking for.

Some [very old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json) do not natively provide the `JSON` object, but you can use [a shim library](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) for those browsers.

Comment: I did indeed try that,but

     toJson: function () {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }

returns null.

Comment: You misunderstand `toJSON`.  If it exists, `JSON.stringify` *calls* the object's `toJSON` method and then serializes *the object that function returns*.  If `toJSON` does not exist, `stringify` simply serializes the object.

Comment: I beg your pardon. 'toJson' was my own choice of name for the function. I gather 'twas a poor choice...

Comment: That's very kind, thanks for your effort, but I'm afraid I can't declare my objects in that way, I'm locked into my (example's) way of doing it so I have to new the objects up, e.g.

 var logEntry = new LogEntry(
                /* conference ID */ "fsdfa",
                /* token Id */ null,
                /* logType */ 1,
                /* logValue */ 1);

Comment: Even using Resig's simple inheritance library, [`JSON.stringify` works correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/6CaY4/).

Comment: Exactly what I was doing(!), but you made it work where I couldn't. Thank you for your time & patience.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [`JSON.stringify()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: I did indeed try that,but

     toJson: function () {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }

returns null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stringify if you want.  Javascript is also really freakin' cool and allows you to pass context abstracts so you really don't need to define class members as you are.  I don't know what your end goal is but check this:

```
function foo(context) { 
    dosomething(context.bar);
}
```

You can dynamically add an arbitrary number of members with simple declarations, making context a JSON object inherently like this:

```
context.bar = "hello world";
```

This way when you pass 'context' to the server, there's no real need to "stringify" it (assuming your backend framework has some sort of JSON parsing that is).

Edit: I got a little off topic, I just hate seeing long strings of params in JS